# AFNetwoking post two requests almost at the same time, the responses are chaotic

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to get data from server. And in my AppDelegate, I post two requests almost at the same time , and response1 sometime returned to request2 and request1 was time out.
This is my http client class, is there some thing wrong? Please help me with this, thank you so much.

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking.h>

@interface HttpClient : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

+ (instancetype)sharedHTTPClient;
- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (NSDictionary *)getDataWithDictionary : (NSDictionary *) dic
                                success : (void (^)(NSDictionary* dictionary))success
                                failure : (void (^)(NSError *error))failure
                           networkError : (void (^)(BOOL isNetworkError))networkError;
@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation HttpClient

+ (instancetype)sharedHTTPClient{
    static HttpClient *_sharedHTTPClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedHTTPClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kReachability]];
    });
    return _sharedHTTPClient;
}

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)getDataWithDictionary : (NSDictionary *) dic
                                success : (void (^)(NSDictionary* dictionary))success
                                failure : (void (^)(NSError *error))failure
                           networkError : (void (^)(BOOL isNetworkError))networkError{

        if ([CheckNetwork isExistenceNetwork]) {
        [self POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kReachability,@"/interfaces/"]
        parameters:parameters
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

          }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

          }];

    }else{

    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: What happens if you do request1 alone?

Comment: Perhaps you can share how you're calling `getDataWithDictionary`, as this is almost certainly not a AFNetworking issue. As an aside, I'm unclear as to why `getDataWithDictionary` returns a `NSDictionary`, as it always will return `nil`. Might be better to return the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` that `POST` returns (in case you ever in the future want the ability to cancel the requests and/or test that the operation was created successfully).